# Access Customer Information in XTRF

Tags: xtrf

I am using createCustomer API to create a customer in XTRF and we are able to create a Customer using "customer Name". Here the customer id and password auto generated by XTRF.

We are using signup functionality in our application, which will create a customer in xtrf. I have to send the login details to the customer email address. please provide us any information on this.

Is there any way to get the customer user name and password, when it is created?

Answer (score 0):

Obtaining customer user name and password is not available in XTRF WebService API.

In the future we plan adding a method for setting customer password.